# Swing : best way to implement zoom functionality in image component

Tags: java, swing, image-editor

I've create a SWING component JImageEditor which simply displays a picture. The idea is to add more functionality to the component further down the road.

One functionality which I've already implemented is zooming. Right now, this part is taken care of in the paintComponent() method. However, somehow I suspect that this might be a bad idea as this means the image will be scaled from the original size to the current "zoom size" each and every time paintComponent() is invoked. The paintComponent code goes as follows :

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
    int w = getWidth();
    int h = getHeight();
    double imageWidth = scale * image.getWidth();
    double imageHeight = scale * image.getHeight();
    double x = (w - imageWidth) / 2;
    double y = (h - imageHeight) / 2;
    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y);
    at.scale(scale, scale);
    g2.drawRenderedImage(image, at);
}
```

Now, what I though of as an alternative was to keep two instances of BufferedImage where one is the original and one is the current "view". That way I could handle the actual zooming/scaling whenever the setScale() method is invoked, instead of scaling in paintComponent(). However, the drawback is that i need to keep two instances of BufferedImage which will lead to higher memory consumption depending on the image size. It is, of course, impossible to predict how large images any given user will open using the component.

What I'm looking for is either a thumbs up if I am on the right track with my work, or thumbs down If it's bad design and some other solution should be considered. I appreciate all input, and will reward all answers which enlightens me :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say put a timing section in your paintComponent to measure how long it takes.  Get your base measure from what you have now.  Then implement the optimized method with the extra BufferedImage.  Compare the measurements and pick the one that is smaller.  I have a feeling your intuition is correct that doing the affine transform every paint cycle is slow, and by creating a double buffer for the scaled image and the source will be faster.  Although I can't find any thing out there that confirms or denies this, and it could be affected by hardware acceleration.

If you extracted that section of code into a ZoomableBufferedImage class you could easily turn on or off the optimized/unoptimized versions.  The ZoomableBufferedImage would hold a reference to the source image, and contain a extra buffered image that it can keep the scaled version in.  As you zoom in/out the ZoomableBufferedImage draws to the buffer or not based on its settings, then in it's paint method it can draw either from the buffer or by applying the AffineTransform to the source and drawing that based on it's settings.